# Unused xib appears in application

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xib

I am now developing an update version of my application that is in app store. In the old version Main Interface is set to MainWindow.xib which loads RootViewController.xib. But in the new version i deleted both xib files and so in application properties(info.plist file) the Main Interface is not set.

When i install the updated application on a iphone which has the older version, the RootWindow.xib appears. When i deleted the application an install the updated version again, the RootWindow.xib doesn't appear.

I am worrying about if i submit my new version to the store, will the RootWindow.xib appear on phones that have older version of my application?

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, when you update you create links to your classes so if you have this xib removed don´t worry. it´s not going to appear

Comment: But why it appears on simulator and my development devices(all of them have the older version of my application). Installing the application through Xcode differs from installing from app store???

Comment: It´s because you needed to clean your project before of launch

Comment: Clean, rebuild doesn't solve the problem. Only deleting and reinstalling is the solution. But after googling around installing through Xcode behaves different than installing from App Store. When you install from App Store, application's old source files are deleted(not the files that created by application). But when you install through Xcode it replaces the files, doesn't deletes the old files.